# Any way to make elementary better on low DPI screens?

Tags: release-loki, settings, display

I have installed elementary on a very old laptop with a very low resolution (1024x800). Some of the windows are cut off at the bottom so I can't access them. Here are some screenshots:
[image: Settings cut off]

[image: Guake preferences cut off]

I have tried to lower the interface scaling but it is already at 1.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself yet...but you might be able to get what you want using xrandr

In a terminal type

```
xrandr --current
```

This is list your display interfaces. Run the next command replacing 
eDP-0 for your display.

```
xrandr --output eDP-0 --scale 0.95x0.95
```

The default setting is 1x1. Anything smaller will "shrink" the objects on the screen and give you a more usable display...in theory. Play with the settings in small increments - nothing drastic. The settings likely will not stick upon logout, so you might want to take the command and add it to you start up. This can be done within the elementary system settings or elementary tweaks.